# JavaScript can't delete div from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I am having an issue deleting or replacing a div with a either an empty div or a new veriosn of the div. I have tried to destroy  the div with delete $targetname I've tried to replace the div with $("#divname").replace() and I seem to be missing some. I have the function tied to a button click that also clears a textarea and that part works fine but my form continues to show the divs that are getting appended but never removed. Below is the link to the fiddle for my code, any help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/fNfK8/

```
emWindow = window.open("", null, "height=400,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");


emWindow.document.title = "Emote Builder";
emWindow.document.body.style.background = "#00214D";
emWindow.document.body.style.color = "White";

// create a form and set properties
var emForm = document.createElement('form');
emForm.id = 'emForm';
// insert into the body of the new window
emWindow.document.body.appendChild(emForm);

// add text before the input
var emoteBuildL = document.createElement('emoteBuildL');
emForm.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Emote Build Window:'));

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);

// add a text input
var emoteBuild = document.createElement('textarea');
emoteBuild.type = 'text';
emoteBuild.name = 'emoteBuild';
emoteBuild.id = 'emoteBuild';
emoteBuild.rows = 6;
emoteBuild.cols = 80;
emoteBuild.value = '';
emForm.appendChild(emoteBuild);

var emoteTosend = document.getElementById('emoteBuild');

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);

var ePreview = document.createElement('button');
ePreview.type = 'button';
ePreview.innerHTML = 'Preview Emote';
ePreview.onclick = emoteFunc;

emForm.appendChild(ePreview);
var eSubmit = document.createElement('button');
eSubmit.type = 'button';
eSubmit.innerHTML = 'Send Emote';
eSubmit.onclick = function () {
    client.send_direct("" + emoteBuild.value);
};
emForm.appendChild(eSubmit);

var eClear = document.createElement('button');
eClear.type = 'button';
eClear.innerHTML = 'Clear Emotes';
eClear.onclick = function () {
    emoteBuild.value = '';
    delete $emPreviews;

};

emForm.appendChild(eClear);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var emotePviewL = document.createElement('emotePviewL');
emForm.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Emote Previews:'));
//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);


//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);

function emoteFunc() {

    var emPreview = emoteBuild.value;
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/%%(.+?)%%/g, "\<font color=\"red\"\>\"$1\"\</font\>");
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/%%/g, "\"");
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/\^/g, "");
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/(\w+_him)/g, "(him/her)");
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/(\w+_his)/g, "(his/her)");
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/(\w+_he)/g, "(he/she)");
    emPreview = emPreview.replace(/#/g, "");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.class = 'emPreviews';
    div.id = 'emPreviews';
    div.style.color = "black";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    div.innerHTML = emPreview;
    emForm.appendChild(div);
    emForm.appendChild(linebreak);
}
```

Comment: `el.parentNode.removeChild(el);`

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't appear to do anything at all.

Comment: If you enter some text in the form it will create a preview below on the preview, the submit won't work, and the clear works just not for the div.

Comment: I have used this in the clear onClick function and still does not clear the old item from the window  var elem = document.getElementById("emPreviews");
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

Comment: Probably very much more efficient to add the content using *document.write*, then call *document.close* before going further. A *type* attribute is not valid for a *textarea* element in an HTML document. What are *emoteBuildL* and *emotePviewL* elements in an HTML document? Why use obsolete (in HTML5) *font* elements instead of *span* with styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it very much more efficient to put the HTML into a separate file and use that as the source for the new window. Alternatively, use *document.write* to add content to the page, e.g. the following replaces about 20 lines at the start of your script:

```
function openWin() {
  var emWindow = window.open("", null, "height=400,width=800,status=yes");

  emWindow.document.write(
    '<!doctype html><title>Emote Builder<\/title>' +
    '<style type="text/css">body{background-color: #00214D;color:White;}<\/style>' +
    '<form id="emForm">' +
    'Emote Build Window:<br>' +
    '<textarea name="emoteBuild" id="emoteBuild" rows="6" cols="80"><\/textarea>'
  );
  emWindow.document.close();
}
```

Note that when you do:

```
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
```

it creates an element in the *current* document, but then:

```
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);
```

appends it to an element in a different document. You really should do:

```
var linebreak = emWindow.document.createElement('br');
emForm.appendChild(linebreak);
```

Or just put it in the HTML above.

You are also creating a button in the opener window, appending it to the form, then having it call a function in the opener. The new window has a new global context, it doesn't have access to the opener's scope. You can do:

```
ePreview.onclick = window.opener.emoteFunc;
```

or similar but you might find that blocked in some browsers.

I'd suggest you re–write the function to firstly generate the HTML you want, then write it to a new window using *emWindow.document.write*. Don't forget to call *emWindow.document.close* at the end.

#### Edit

Remember that you are working across documents. So if you are still running the script in the opener (the original window), you have to preface any reference to methods in the child window with a reference to *emWindow*, e.g. to get a reference to the form in the child window you have to use:

```
function emoteFunc() {

    // Get a reference to the form in the child window
    var emPreview = emWindow.document.getElementById('emoteBuild');
    ...

    // Create a div in the child window to append to it
    var div = emWidnow.document.createElement('div');
    ...

    // The form and div are in the same document, so just append
    emForm.appendChild(div);

    // Create a BR element in the child and append it
    emForm.appendChild(emWindow.document.createElement('br'));
    ...
}
```

#### Edit 2

Here is a trivial example of sending data between a child and opener.

```
<script>

var win;

function newWin(){
    win = window.open('','','');

    win.document.write(
      '<title>new window<\/title>' +
      '<script>function getValue() {' +
      'document.getElementById("i0").value = opener.document.forms.f0.i0.value;}<\/script>' +
      '<input id="i0">' +
      '<input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="Get value from opener">' +
      '<input type="button" onclick="opener.getValue()" value="Get value using function in opener">'
    );

    win.document.close();
};

function getValue() {
console.log('getValue called');
console.log(win.document.getElementById('i0').value);

  win.document.getElementById('i0').value = document.f0.i0.value;
}

function sendValue(value) {
  win.document.getElementById('i0').value = value;
}

</script>

<button onclick="newWin()">Open child</button>
<form id="f0">
  <p>Value to get from child
  <input name="i0" value="value in opener">
  <input type="button" value="Send value" onclick="sendValue(this.form.i0.value)">
</form>
```

You will discover that (in IE at least) you can:

1. call a function in the child window to get a value from the opener
2. call a function in the opener to send a value to the child
3. call a function in one window from the other,

but you can't call a function in the other window that updates the current window, that's one too many hops.

So any function you want to call from the child should be in the child, and any function you want to call from the opener should be in the opener.

Comment: Thanks I'm just getting myself used to HTML5 all my experience is quite dated as shown by my coding :). I am still looking for how I'd delete the element so that the page doesn't fill up

Comment: So followed you format and re-wrote the complete form much cleaner thanks! But now my function fails to append to the form and when I try and submit it the window just goes blank.

Comment: OK Thank you so much, get the references properly in the old fixed that but I am still having issues with the new shortened form calling my emoteFunc after I build it. Do I need to do something different when I build the doc with the document write method to call my function?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help this really does make my life easier. I have one question I am trying to get my function embedded in the code for the local window but it seems to be erroring out. If Post it could you help me trouble shoot it, It doesn't seem to like my call to set a variable in the script of or something according to fiddle